# Windows Phone 8.1 & above - is there some equivalent for Apple's keychain

Tags: security, encryption, windows-phone-8.1

I want to store store some app specific secret on the phone - this should be available only for the app & no other app.

I was looking at DPAPI - however, if the user does not have a logon password, then it seems like the master key will be accessible to everyone. Also I am not clear what else to pass as the entropy parameter.